# Does `\AfterBeginEnvironment` command already exist?

Tags: environments, etoolbox

Do you know the commands `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment`? I need a command like `\AfterBeginEnvironment` in order to put some text right aftert my all environments. Is there a way? That command already exists? Because I can't find it.

Comment: This command does not exist because it cannot be generic like the others because it depends if the environments takes arguments, and what kind of arguments it takes (a similar question was asked some weeks ago, I'll try to find it). Patching the environment you want to change might be easier. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I def a * \newtheorem * environment. I just need more vertical space after the title. @PhelypeOleinik Ty.

Comment: That is much easier (I think). Can you please show a minimal example of your document (with the `\documentclass` you use and packages you load), please? And do you want to add that space for a single theorem type or for all of them?

Comment: Why don't you rephrase your question to ask what you actually want, with a compliable [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), and then people can try to help. The [xpatch](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package might be what you need.

Comment: Since there is *no* vertical space between a theorem title and the statement, because usually the title is inline, an example of what you're doing is necessary. If you use a “break style, and want to move the title further from the statement, don't: your readers will be grateful (more so if you don't use a paper wasting break style).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I think you could transform your initial comment into an answer.

Comment: @pluton Done (2 more to go...)

Answer (score 5):

The structure of an environment `FOO` when `etoolbox` is loaded is (roughly):

```latex
% \begin{FOO}
\before@begin@FOO
\begingroup
  \at@begin@FOO
  \FOO % <- actual environment code
  % \after@begin@FOO
  <environment body>
% \end{FOO}
  \at@end@FOO
  \endFOO % <- end environment code
\endgroup
\after@end@FOO
```

Your proposition of adding an `\AfterBeginEnvironment` would add the (commented) `\after@begin@FOO` hook, which *would* work for simple cases (why wouldn't it, right?). The problem is that if the environment takes an argument (optional or otherwise) the `\after@begin@FOO` hook would get in the way of the `<environment body>` (which may include the arguments to `\FOO`) and the grabbed arguments would be incorrect. This is why there isn't a `\AfterBeginEnvironment`.

A `\AfterEndEnvironment` *could* exist, since the `\end` part of an environment shouldn't take arguments, but that may not *always* be the truth, so that isn't implemented either. The hooks are only added where the implementation of the environment isn't affected by the hook.

For your specific case of adding more vertical space after the title of a theorem environment, you need to check the documentation of the theorem package you are using and find a hook in there to change the spacing, which should be easier than implementing a `\AfterBeginEnvironment`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to patch the [`exam`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) class to insert page breaks before questions `part` items, using `\xpretocmd` worked just fine. Your case would call for `\xapptocmd`. Maybe `\apptocmd` works as well, if your environment does not have optional arguments.

This works because a command `\newenvironment{envname}{<before code>}{<after code>}` will define two macros, `\envname` (before code) and `\endenvname` (end code). Thus appending code to `\envname` will effectively append to the `<before code>`. This would be exactly where `\after@begin@FOO` sits [in the existing answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494409/does-afterbeginenvironment-command-already-exist/540667#540667). Others have also commented on how `xpatch` might be the correct choice here. It's not an answer yet, so I thought adding it makes sense.

You didn't specify a use case or MWE, so I'm just going to show how I patched `exam`s `parts` environment (which defines `part` and `bonuspart` in its `<before code>`). `AtBeginEnvironment` and `BeforeBeginEnvironment` didn't cut it, since any `\def\part...` command was overwritten again by the `<before code>`'s own `\def\part`. Only *appending* at the very end ensured we overwrite the existing `\def\part`:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{xpatch}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% New page before every question *part*
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Problem: `exam` doesn't just define `\part` on the top-level, but only *inside* the
% `parts` environment. The reason given in `exam.cls` is:
%
%     We want the \part command to be defined *only* inside of a parts
%     environment, so that the user can use the standard sectioning \part
%     command inside of a questions environment (as long as it's outside of
%     a parts environment).
%
% This means we cannot simply redefine `\part`, we need to wait until a `parts`
% environment is started, then at the end of its environment code run our patch.
% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494409/120853

\xapptocmd{\parts}{%
    \xpretocmd{\part}{\clearpage}{%
        % Success code
    }{%
        % Failure code
    }
    \xpretocmd{\bonuspart}{\clearpage}{%
        % Success code
    }{%
        % Failure code
    }
}{
    % Success code
}{%
    % Failure code
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Base question.
        \begin{parts}
            \part Hello from the next page!
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```